# Sheets Forms Data Manipulation and Deleting Rows if Certain Cells are Blank

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This question is similar to "Forms Data Manipulation In Google Sheets" (https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/88736/forms-data-manipulation-in-google-sheets) but requires a bit more automation:

Background: Users fill out a google form for a request and have the option of repeating those same questions to fill out a second, third, fourth, and fifth request. I have created a sheet that will manipulate these rows so that rows with identical columns will be transferred to one column.

Here is my example sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11DM7z_vwuR1S6lgMN7Wu7a0GoouVc2_5xj6nZ1Ozj5I/edit#gid=1967901028

**Form Responses**: sheet that returns the responses from users filling out form

**Manipulated Rows:** sheet that returns manipulated rows using:
=OFFSET('Form Responses'!$A$2,ceiling((row()-row($B$1))/5,1)-1,column()-column($B$1),1,COUNTA($B$1:$D$1)) **in cell B2,** 
and

=OFFSET('Form Responses'!$A$2,ceiling((row()-row($B$1))/5,1)-1,mod(row()-(row($B$1)+1),5)*COUNTA($E$1:$N$1)+COUNTA($B$1:$D$1),1,COUNTA($E$1:$N$1)) 
**in cell E2**

**Paste Values**: this sheet returns a paste values of **Manipulated Rows**, excluding the Offset formula and then deleting any rows that have blank cells E-N. Here is the apps script reflected in the 'Paste Values' tab:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

//Duplicate sheet 'Manipulated Rows' as paste values
function moveValuesOnly() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Paste Values');
  var source = ss.getRange('Manipulated Rows!A1:T100000');
  source.copyTo(ss.getRange('Paste Values!A1'), {contentsOnly: true});
  deleteRows(sheet);
}

//Function to Delete empty rows:
function deleteRows(sheet) {
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var range_manipulated_rows = ss.getSheetByName('Manipulated Rows!A1:T100000');
  var range_paste_values = ss.getSheetByName('Paste Values!A1:T100000');
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  var rowsDeleted = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    if (range_manipulated_rows == range_paste_values && row[4] == '' && row[5] == '' && row[6] == '' && row[7] == '' && row[8] == '' && row[9] == '' 
        && row[10] == '' && row[11] == '' && row[12] == '' && row[13] == '') { // if paste values tab is equal to manipulated rows tab and cell E-N are blank
      sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
      rowsDeleted++;
    }
  }
};
```

**I want to make this more automated by creating an apps script that will directly convert the sheet of 'Form Responses' to the sheet of 'Paste Values' without using Manipulated Rows. As in the 'Paste Values' sheet, it needs to remove any rows where all of cells E-N are blank.**

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. You want to directly convert the sheet of ``Form Responses`` to the sheet of ``Paste Values`` without using ``Manipulated Rows``. Is my understanding correct? 2. Is your sample Spreadsheet the latest one? If you want to change the question, at first, please update it. I would like to refer the latest one.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike yes, that is correct. I have updated the question, and my sample spreadsheet is the latest one. Thanks so much!

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about the additional question. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, what you said is correct; I want to directly convert the sheet of Form Responses to the sheet of Paste Values without using Manipulated Rows

Comment: Thank you for replying. I cannot understand about your additional question yet. Can I ask you about the detail information of it? I would like to think of your solution after I could correctly understand it.

Comment: @Tanaike In the finalized sheet, I would also like to do additional things with it such as send automated emails and record in cells when the emails got sent out (cells O-T in 'Manipulated Rows' sheet are triggered by what 'Status' column A says). I already have the code to do this, but ideally, the finalized sheet would be able to have this functionality as well and not cause any error to these cells or cause them to change in any way

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your inisial question, I could understand that you want to directly convert the sheet of ``Form Responses`` to the sheet of ``Paste Values`` without using ``Manipulated Rows``. About your additional question, I couldn't understand yet. If I could correctly understand about your questions, I would like to think of your current issue. I apologize for this situation.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, in my current solution, the 'Paste Values' sheet has an On Edit trigger that sometimes returns the rows incorrectly. I'm trying to find a solution that's more efficient than the code I currently have. The details of my second question don't really matter, but to put it another way, I'm just looking for a more efficient solution than what I already have. So any help on the first question would be helpful, thank you!

Comment: Thank you for replying. About ``an On Edit trigger that sometimes returns the rows incorrectly.``, I cannot understand. If I could replicate your issue, I would like to think of the solution.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, the second part of the question does not matter; I would just like to directly convert the sheet of Form Responses to the sheet of Paste Values without using Manipulated Rows. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to confirm about the result you want, because I would like to completer it. 1. You want to copy values of "Form Response" to "Paste Values" using Google Apps Script. 2. There are 9 cycles of "Address" to "Do you have another printer request?" of the columns of "D" to "CO". 9 cycles are constant. Is my understanding correct? Please tell me whether there are requests except for above.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, I have updated the google sheets above. So there is a google form where users can fill out columns E-M  up to five times, indicated by the question in column N ('Do you have another printer request?'). 'Manipulated Rows' returns these questions row by row, but not every request is filled up to 5 times. So I want to to eliminate  rows that are empty in Manipulated rows from E to M. Please let me know if that makes sense

Comment: Thank you for replying. 1. You want to convert the values of "Form Response" to "Manipulated Rows" using Google Apps Script. 2. There are 5 cycles of "Address" to "Do you have another printer request?" of the columns of "D" to "AZ". The data might be 1 cycle and 3 cycles. But The maximum 5 cycles are constant. Is my understanding correct? Please tell me whether there are requests except for above.

Comment: @Tanaike Yes, the maximum 5 cycles are constant. Users can fill out a form for 1 cycle, 2 cycles, 3 cycles, 4 cycles, or 5 cycles. I want to convert the values of "Form Response" to the "Paste Values" sheet without using "Manipulated Rows". Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for replying. When you give me a time to prepare the sample script, I'm glad.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, thank you, whenever you are able to help if you would like, I would appreciate it!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I posted an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, thank you, this works- the only issue is that when a user submits a form, if I add an On Edit trigger to this form, the rows will accumulate to the bottom, rather than just adding the new row alone. This means that the rows get duplicated. I can try to modify this script though- thank you for your help!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your question was resolved. About your new question, I couldn't understand about it. So in order to correctly understand your new issue, can you post it as new question by including the detail information for replicating your issue? It will help users including me think of the solution. Also I would like to confirm about your new issue. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, I have posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55716140/google-apps-script-sheets-forms-data-manipulation-deleting-rows-if-certain-cel if you are able to help, thank you!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will check it. If I could understand about your question, I would like to propose a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to directly convert the values of "Form Response" to "Paste Values" using Google Apps Script.
- There are 5 cycles of "Address" to "Do you have another printer request?" of the columns of "D" to "AZ". The data might be 1 cycle and 3 cycles. But The maximum 5 cycles are constant.

From your question and comments, I could understand above. How about this sample script?

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var src = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses");
  var dst = ss.getSheetByName("Paste Values");
  var values = src.getDataRange().getValues();
  var header = values.splice(0, 1)[0].splice(0, 13);
  var res = values.reduce(function(ar, e) {
    var h = e.splice(0, 3);
    h.unshift("");
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      var temp = e.splice(0, 10);
      if (temp.filter(String).length == 0) continue;
      if (temp.length < 10) temp.splice(temp.length, 10 - temp.length, "");
      ar.push(h.concat(temp));
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  if (dst.getRange("A1").getValue() != "Status") res.unshift(["Status"].concat(header));
  dst.getRange(dst.getLastRow() + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
}
```

#### Note:

- In this sample script, the sheet names of `Form Responses` and `Paste Values` are used. If you want to change the sheet name, please modify the script.
- In this sample script, the header row of the sheet of `Paste Values` is automatically set. If you don't want to set this, please modify the script.

#### References:

- [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)